# django retrieve fields from few tables in template

Tags: django, django-templates

```
class PlannedOTList(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    planned_surgery = models.TextField(verbose_name='diagnosis and planned surgery', blank=True) # decided by the committee
    planned_date_of_surgery = models.DateField('date of surgery', null=True, blank=True)
    planned_date_of_admission = models.DateField('date of admission', null=True, blank=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)
    surgery_set = models.BooleanField('required surgery set', default=False)
    # to_be_admitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = PlannedOTListQS.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'planned_ot_list'
        ordering = ['-date_added']

class Admission(models.Model):
    # general info
    date_admission = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class OperationNotesList(models.Model):
    admission=models.ForeignKey(Admission,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    #patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    procedure_code=models.CharField(max_length=7)
    diagnosis_code=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='op_created_by')
    pre_operation_list=models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    intra_operation_list=models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    post_operation_list=models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    is_done=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table='operationNotesList'

class Patient(models.Model):
    patientid_generated_part = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='', blank=True)
    date_recorded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'patients'
        ordering = ['-modified']
```

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><label >Proposed Operation: &nbsp
    {{ operationnoteslist.admission.patient.planned_ot_list.planned_surgery }}</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><label >Weight: &nbsp
    {{ operationnoteslist.admission.weight }}&nbsp(kg)</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><label >Height: &nbsp
    {{ operationnoteslist.admission.height }}&nbsp(cm)</label></div>    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><label >BMI: &nbsp
    {{ operationnoteslist.admission.bmi }}</label></div>
</div>
```

the html code above has the main model `operationnoteslist`. 
I am trying to get values from planned_ot_list. I don't know what I am missing.

I thought the way to go is: `MyownModelTable.foreignTablename.foreignTablename.field`

The Proposed operation does not retrieve any values.

Comment: You don't have `planned_ot_list` field/foreign key in your Patient model. This is why your data is not rendering as excepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As reply to the comment: There is no need for a `planned_ot_list` in the `Patient` model.)

Reverse relations (one to many) have by default a `_set` suffix. Also, in your `PlannedOTList` model, patient has not the `unique` flag so a patient can have several of those related to them. And on top, the model relation name in lowercase has no underscores (camel case is simply lower cased). So the reverse relation name should be:

```
patient.plannedotlist_set
```

(You can print out the available properties using `dir(patient)`, the output will include the reverse relation properties.)

This returns a query manager and you cannot simply write `patient.plannedotlist_set.planned_surgery`. Instead, you have to decide whether to display the complete list or only one of its entries. If they have a natural order and you want to use the first or last, you can do this:

```
patient.plannedotlist_set.first  # in the template or first() in view
patient.plannedotlist_set.last
```

To iterate over all of them use:

```
patient.plannedotlist_set.all  # template or all() in view
```

Note that you should give the PlannedOTList an ordering to make this work, either by adding a Meta property like this:

```
Meta:
    ordering = ('field1', 'field2', ...)  # use '-field1' for reverse
```

Or, if the ordering is dependent of the view, order in the view and add the list to the template context explicitly.